# Find occurrences of objects in list

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I've this class:

```
public class FileInformation
{

    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I add data to:

```
List<FileInformation> theConfigFiles = new List<FileInformation>();
theConfigFiles.Add(new FileInformation() { Category= xxx,  Message = yyyy});
```

How can I get the occurrences of "OK" in Message? I need to count the number of "OK" in Message.

Comment: Sounds like a real need and not a homework...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var count = theConfigFiles.Count(f => f.Message.Contains("OK"))
```

Note that this is a case sensitive search.  If the message contains "ok" it will not be found.  If you want your search to be case insensitive then just call `.ToLower()`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the occurrences of "OK" in Message? I need to count the number of "OK" in Message.

I'm not sure if you mean that you need to count the number of occurrences of the string "OK" in every Message field (i.e., Message="OKOK" has two), or the number of Message fields which contain "OK".

I'll assume the latter:

```
int count = theConfigFiles.Count(f => f.Message.Contains("OK"));
```

Comment: @Ek0nomik: Yeah, but because of my stupid analysis you beat me :D